# call recursion method in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, recursion

[image]

How do I call a recursion inside the Vue instance? The method called inside only runs one time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Remove the `.$options.methods` part. Just `_self.getPlanTask` is sufficient. You don't need to use `_self` either, `this.getPlanTask` should work fine.